# apache2 redirect of different subdirectory to different subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a subdomain in a server that point to the root
`subdomain.example.com`

I have to add two other subdomains that point to 2 different subdirectoris

`test1.example.com -> /test1`

`test2.example.com -> /test2`

I modified the .htaccess file:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test1.example.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test2.example.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test2/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

but from the apache2 log I reeive a

```
 Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

and obviously a serve 500 error for test1 and test2, the main subdomain works fine.

what's wrong in my code?
is there an alternative way?

Comment: You redirect from `test1.example.com/..` to `test1.example.com/test1/...` - so on the next round, the RewriteCond is still true, and it redirects again.

Comment: Yes you are all right thenk you so, in your opinion i have to specify the full name of  the main subdomain?

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test1.subdomain.example.com`

Comment: If you make the substitution a full absolute URL using the `subdomain.example.com` host name, then this will cause an external redirect. If you want to keep `test1.example.com` in the browser address bar, then you can't do that. You need to stop it from redirecting again then, by checking whether the current path is not `test1/` already.

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood, can you please give an example?